# Whats the difference between the comparison and logical "not" operator?

Tags: javascript

I'm having a hard time understanding the difference between the comparison and logical "not" operators in Javascript. And I am confused about the syntax as well. My questions are:

Since they are both boolean operators, are there any real differences between the two?

And is the syntax for both like this?
x! = 5

Any explanation appreciated - please post examples if you can.

Comment: `x! = 5` doesn't even compile.

Comment: `!x` and `x != 5` are different things.

Comment: `x != y` is conceptually equivalent to `!(x==y)` while `!x == y` is very different and `!x = y` doesn't even compile.

Comment: I need more explanation to understand: I believe x! = y is the correct syntax when using the comparison "not" - operator?

Comment: @KennethHayes `!expr` is the logical negation (not) operator. `expr != expr` is the inequality operator. It is pronounced "not equals" but `expr ! == expr` (note the space in `! ==`) won't work.

Comment: @KennethHayes No. Spaces are important. `x! = y` is basically gibberish. `!=` is a specific operator that translates to "is not equal to".

Comment: Thx Jan Dvorak - that helps a little, but still not clear to me: can you provide an example of how to use the logical negation !expr in an variable?

Comment: What do you mean? `var y = !x` is valid Javascript that declares `y` as a variable and sets its value to the logical negation of `x`. - is that what you mean?

Comment: `if(!x && !y)` is a valid use of the logical NOT operator.

Comment: Note "variable" basically means "a memory location". A combination of operators, operands, function calls... is called an "expression".

Comment: @dystroy Javascript doesn't compile anyway.

Comment: @Chiel92 it does compile in the browser. That's why `eval` is so slow - it runs uncompiled code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparison: take two values and compare them. We could ask various questions, for example:

- are these two values "the same", we use == for that
- is this value bigger than that value, >
- is this value bigger than *or* equal to that, >=

The result of each of this is a boolean value. So we could write:

boolean areTheyEqual = ( x == y );

So aretheyEqual would be "true" if x was equal to y. Now suppose you wanted a variable "areTheyDifferent". We could get that in two ways, either using the "not" operator, which works on a boolean value:

```
boolean areTheyDifferent = ! areTheyEqual;
```

or we could use the "notEqual" comparison

```
boolean areTheyDifferent = ( x != y );
```

So the ! operator takes a boolean value and "inverts" it. You need to read the

```
!=
```

as a single comparison operator, just like >= is a single operator.

Answer (score 1):

Comparison operators are used in logical statements to determine equality or difference between variables or values.
eg               `x!=y`

Logical operators are used to determine the logic between variables or values.

eg               `!(x==y)`

Comment: Thx Sankalp for posting your answer